# pgAdmin 4 does not create functions with geometry

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, pgadmin-4

I started recently using pgAdmin 4 after having used pgAdmin 3 for a long time.

The problem I have now is that I cannot replace existing functions that reference `geometry` objects. I am on Windows 10, and the current version of pgAdmin 4 is 2.1.

The PL/pgSQL function already exists in the database and it was created with flyway, psql or pgAdmin 3, and it works.
The PostGIS extension is enabled.

Now I go in pgAdmin 4 and use the same login as ever, choose "Scripts"->"Create script" for the function, and then click F5 - "run Script" to create it.

What I get is an error:

```
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 22:   v_location   geometry;
```

The same operation in pgAdmin 3 gives no error.
The function has the `search_path` set correctly and can be created in pgAdmin3 and psql.

Actually I can create a dummy function in the query tool in pgadmin4 and compile it. See below:

```
set search_path=res_cc_01,public;
create or replace function test() returns text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  set search_path=res_cc_01,public
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_g geometry := ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(142.279859 -9.561480)',4326);
begin
    return 'xxx'::text;
end;
$BODY$
```

Only when recompiling through Scripts->Create Script then F5 ( Execute ) I got the error.
What is the problem here?

I could not find a similar problem on the net, nor into the manuals. But I haven't read them all.

Answer (score 2):

You're certainly missing the `postgis` extension in the current database. If you already have it installed in your server, just execute the following command to create the extension and so the missing data type:

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

If it happens to be that you don't have it installed in your database server, you can find the installation instructions to many operating systems **[here](https://postgis.net/install/)**.

Comment: Thank your for the fast answer, but this does not solve the problem. The postgis extension and others  are already installed, the code is already running on the database, I only tried to make a small fix and compile it with PGAdmin4 using the Scripts->create scritps how I often did it in pgadmin 3. Compiling he changes with PGAdmin 3 is working. So it seems to me that this is a pgadmin 4 problem and not a server problem. 
Actually we use set search_path = mypath,public in the plpgsql code definition of the function, probably this is not working in pgadmin 4.

Comment: That's really intriguing.. what happens if you paste the code of your function in a query tool window and try to execute it? I assume you have a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` statement. I also use pgAdmin 4 (not a big fan though) with postgis and it works fine for me.

Comment: I added the query tool test  function in the main thread. It is working there but not with Create Scripts.

Comment: Now I see what you mean: I also got the same error : `ERROR:  FEHLER:  Typ »geometry« existiert nicht
LINE 16:     v_g geometry := ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(142.279859 -9...` I will upvote your question to see if somebody else knows the answer for what seems to be a bug to me. I will let you know if I find something.

Comment: Servus! I just see that pgAdmin4 is not coping well with this parameter `SET search_path='res_cc_01, public'` in your function. Leaving it out you can compile the function.. which is not a solution at all, but at least we know where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! Now you've nailed it. The problem here is the way Create Script displays the code. It adds quotes to the schema names in the set search_path directive which makes the path invalid. Actually the function was created using set search_path=res_cc_01,public; but was displayed as set search_path='res_cc_01,public' which is an invalid path.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the way pgadmin 4 shows the plpgsql code when using Scripts-> Create Script.
It adds unneeded quotes to the paths in the search_path directive that makes the entire search_path invalid. With an invalid search_path the compiler will not find the available extensions.
We actually have an item with PGAdmin4 with Scripts->Create Script malfunction.
In PgAdmin 3 the search_path directive used in the function was showed as alter function statement but in a correct form.
Many thanks to Jim Jones for the precious analysis on this problem.